# Jquery script wont see the difference between the 2 div's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a database with my projects, Table called: Projects. In this table i have 3 columns:

```
ID, Titel, BLOB
```

This is my php:

```
  {
  echo '<div class="project_box">';
  echo '<p class="project_text">' . $row['titel'] . '</p>';
  echo '<img class="project_box_image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" width="200" height="200"</img>';
  echo '</div>';
  }
```

Every ting loads already into my website, but now i want to check if the titel equals to something, with jQuery.

Now I have this code, but it works only for 1 div. If I make a second div in my database it loads in my website but when i click each of them it says alert "test".

It seems my code wont see the difference between the 2 title's in my div's

```
$('.project_box').click(function() {
    if ($('.project_text').text() == "Portefolio"){
        window.location.href = "portefolio/";
    }else if ($('.project_text').text() == "test"){
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

`.project_box` is the div I load my, title and BLOB in, and on click I want to check project text equals to something.

`.project_text` is the title text of the project.

I hope its clear for you, it would really help my out!

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that it will solve your problem:

Better Way use `children()`:
replace your jquery by this:

```
 $('.project_box').click(function() {
     var strText = $(this).children(".project_text").text();
    if (strText == "Portefolio"){
        alert("portefolio");
    }else if (strText == "test"){
        alert('test');
    }
  });
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/676/

Comment: It only works because the text inside `project_text` is the only one in the box. If you decide (later) to add more text to the box (but not the title), this won't work anymore.

Comment: ye i thought about something like that, because the title was not defined in a class or something.
But the title was in this case the most important thing, for now. if i decide to add a extra class like: project_extra_text, it wouldnt affect for the onclick with your script:) am i right? 

Again, THANKS!

Comment: @user3313356: if it works or help you should accept an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

When you have multiple `<p class="project_text">` how do you think jQuery interprets `$('.project_text')`? You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the class that is inside the clicked box.

```
$('.project_box').click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.project_text').text() == "Portefolio"){
        window.location.href = "portefolio/";
    }else if ($(this).find('.project_text').text() == "test"){
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

I think a `switch()` would be better here as well, saves you writing the `.text()` part multiple times.

```
$('.project_box').click(function() {
    switch ($(this).find('.project_text').text()) {
        case "Portefolio":
            window.location.href = "portefolio/";
            break;
        default:
            alert("test");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought about a case in the first scenario but when my if else not worked i thought it wouldnt work.
But this case is much better;) thanks again!

Comment: They are perfectly interchangeable. The problem as I said was that you now have to classes, so `$('.project_text')` doesn't return a single object anymore.